# Looking for an anime where in one of the scenes the guy and he is some sort of demon or god

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember the one specific scene of the anime where the main character is a guy with dark hair, and I think he is wearing an orange jumpsuit, and he suddenly loses it, and he starts his chant of something like “death, die”, and he ends up killing all of his friends in a field of wheat (?) they were being trained for something, military maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I found it! It’s from [The Legend of the Legendary Heroes](https://myanimelist.net/anime/8086/Densetsu_no_Yuusha_no_Densetsu).